# add the total amount without VAT in cart prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, cart, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.7

**Hi everyone**,

I want to add in my cart the total order without VAT where can i find the source code page of this please? 
**Regards**

Answer (score 0):

you can remove that following these steps:

1) To successfully remove the VAT indication on the ajax popup that shows VAT go over to:

```
NAMEOFTHEWEBSITE/themes/THEMENAME/modules/ps_shoppingcart
```

2) On the file modal.tpl, line 64, you can comment the taxshort. So, the line looks like:

```
<p><strong>{l s='Total:' d='Shop.Theme.Checkout'}</strong>&nbsp;{$cart.totals.total.value} {*{$cart.labels.tax_short}*}</p>
```

Also... You can select the 'No' option for Tax on the International - Tax - Enable Tax screen but that did not remove the tax/vat label on the individual product listings. However, if you want no label in cart process you have to delete it from some tpl files.

The code responsible for this label is this {$cart.labels.tax_short} you will find some tpl files where it appears and the path is in:

```
themes/YOURTHEME/templates/checkout/_partials
```

Remove Tax Display from Active Shopping Cart / Basket

```
themes/YOURTHEME/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-detailed-totals.tpl
```

Remove Tax Display from Final Checkout Cart / Confirmation

```
themes/YOURTHEME/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-summary-totals.tpl
```

Remove Tax Display

```
themes/YOURTHEME/templates/checkout/_partials/order-confirmation-table.tpl
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer ! i followed the steps but nothing changed! Imade CNTRL F5 but samething, please where can  i find the twig cart page ? to modify and add text 
tahnks !